# scons + windows: Cannot execute shell script in Command() builder

Tags: windows, bash, scons

I have a command builder as such:

jsontar = Command("bundle.tar", bundleDir, "mkvgconf $SOURCE $TARGET")

mkvgconf is a shell script
$SOURCE is a path to a directory
$TARGET is a path to a file

When attempting to execute under windows, SCons does not recognize vgmkconf as an executable.

Google turns up:
http://www.scons.org/wiki/UsingPkgConfigMsysShellScripts

Using this script, I am able to make a mkvgconf.cmd that SCons DOES recognize and attempts to execute. Unfortunately, SCons passes $SOURCE and $TARGET as UNIX path strings, not windows strings. The path strings are misinterpreted and the build fails.

Question 1: How do I make SCons recognize my shell script without the kludge?

Questions 2: If Question 1 has no solution, how do I make my pathnames are formatted correctly for the build platform?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to execute the bash script, by replacing `mkvgconf $SOURCE $TARGET` with:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "mkvgconf $SOURCE $TARGET"
```